# Passing a parameter into "dotnet publish"

Tags: .net

I currently have a build process that calls

```
dotnet publish
```

to package the application.  Is it possible to pass in a string parameter to be read into the args parameter of my Main method of my application?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

I haven't been able to find any answers for this particular question online, and the documentation doesn't explicitly mention about parameters in the dotnet publish call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x, but I'm wondering if there would be a way around this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the parameters to `Main` are from when it is *executed*, not when it is published; I don't think the feature you're looking for exists

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the clarification! I will need to go down another route.

Comment: still a good question if someone wants to pass some custom parameter during build process